# When i run this code on pycharm it gives an error "Input Error" on the line create table . Is there a syntax error?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect(database='database')

curse=conn.cursor()

curse.execute("""CREATE TABLE Table1 (
name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
surname varchar(128) NOT NULL

```
              """)
```

conn.commit()
conn.close()

Comment: Please edit and provide enough information about your issue. It is unclear what do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing paranthesis. It should be
curse.execute("""CREATE TABLE Table1 ( name varchar(128) NOT NULL, surname varchar(128) NOT NULL ) """)